# C# VSTO Outlook - select multiple items and send them as attachment

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

How do I select multiple items and open new mail form and add all selected items as attachments to the new email so I can send them together with the new email?

I guess, this could be broken into:

1. how to get multiple selected items in outlook (say user selects them all while holding Ctrl key to do multiple selection)?
2. How to open New Email form in Outlook?
3. How to attach selected item in 1 above and add them to the new email as attachments?

**UPDATE**:
So far I have managed to do following (Thanks to Dmitry's comment):

```
public void SendSelectedMailsAsAttachment()
{
    try
    {
        Selection olSelection = HostAddIn.ActiveExplorer.Selection;
        var count = olSelection.Count;
        var items = new List<IItem>();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = HostAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

        foreach (var sel in olSelection)
        {
            oMailItem.Attachments.Add(sel);
        }
        oMailItem.Display(false);
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ex message
    }
}
```

but with this code, following happens:

1. if I select single email and try to send it as attachment, the code above executes just fine and new email form opens but it will show no attachment.
2. if I select multiple emails and try to send them as attachment, the code above will throw exception when calling `oMailItem.Attachments.Add(sel)` for the 2nd time with exception "`This operation is not supported until the entire message is downloaded. Download the message and try again.`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection
2. `Application.CreateItem` / `MailItem.Display`
3. Loop through the items in the  `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection and call `MailItem.Attachments.Add` for each item.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: I added an update, still having problem with attaching items.

Comment: Is that an IMAP4 store? Are messages downloaded?